# How to randomly assign one of four images to a field

Tags: java

So I am doing a project for my JAVA class finals. During the assignment, there is a question ask me to randomly assign one of four images (the flower images I have) to the **image** field in my **Flower** constructor. But I did not seem to understand this requirement. Can somebody help me with this? I will greatly appreciate. Here is my code. Also, my teacher has given us a hint that we should use an "if" statement for this.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class Flower {
    private ImageIcon image; 
    private Point pos; 

    public Flower(int x, int y) {
        pos = new Point(x,y); 
    }

}
```

Comment: And the images to a `List` and use `Collections.shuffle` to randomise the `List`, then just grab the first one, because I'm lazy

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer, since im really new to programming, how can i add all four of them into an ArrayList?

Comment: Perhaps this: `// OPTIONALLY accept a ImageIcon type image within // the Flower constructor. public Flower(int x, int y, ImageIcon... randomImageIcon) {         if (randomImageIcon.length > 0) { this.image = randomImageIcon[0]; }        this.pos = new Point(x,y);  }`

Comment: hey, @DevilsHnd thank you for your help. But how do I actually make the randomImageIcon read the image files? would I have to declare `Imageicon image = new image("_image path_")` first?

Comment: You would do this before creating an instance of Flower: `ImageIcon[] images = {new ImageIcon("your1st.png"), new ImageIcon("your2nd.png"), new ImageIcon("your3rd.png"), new ImageIcon("your4th.png")};` and then `Random rand = new Random(); Flower flower = new Flower(0, 10, images[rand.nextInt(4)]);`.

Answer (score 0):

Generating a random number from 0 to 4 will do the trick for you.
Suppose the 4 images you have is in the form of array of type ImageIcon.
If the name of the array is list_flowers.
your constructor can be-

```
public Flower(int x, int y) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    pos = new Point(x,y);
    image = list_flowers[rand.nextInt(4)];
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much Anju, however, my images are png file types... so I don't think doing that will help with my problem :(

Comment: `public Flower(int x, int y) {
    Random rand = new Random();` The `Random` instance should be declared once, outside the method. Otherwise if the code calls that method from within a loop, the 'random' flower is likely to be exactly the same. Note also that using a random number for an array index is how I or you might do it, but the OP mentions the teacher hinted at using `if` statements. The only way I can figure to incorporate conditional statements is to produce a pair (for 4 images) of boolean values.

Comment: *"my images are png file types"* This answer will work for ***any*** image type. (The `ImageIcon` will work for any image that Java supports in the core API.)

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you for willing to help me! but by using the trick that Anju just stated, our class has not even studied about that yet. Thus, that's why the teacher wants us to do it with the if statement

Comment: *"our class has not even studied about that yet"* GUIs are an advanced subject. Before starting them, a programmer should be familiar with the basics of the language & simple computing concepts like loops and conditional statements, as well as basic data structures such as arrays and collections. So this teacher - throwing the class into making a GUI based app. - is .. not very competent.

Comment: Like we have studied about ArrayList and also collections but we have never used `Random` before.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you need to change `Flower` so you can pass it the image to be used.

```
public class Flower {
    private ImageIcon image; 
    private Point pos; 

    public Flower(ImageIcon image, int x, int y) {
        pos = new Point(x,y); 
    }

}
```

Personal thing, but I prefer it this way, as the result of initialising the class can be reasoned about.

One solution would be to make use of the available functionality in the Java API.  Because I'm lazy, this would mean making use of `Collections.shuffle` to "randomise" a list of objects.

It might go something like....

```
 List<ImageIcon> images = new ArrayList<>(4);
 images.add(new ImageIcon(...)); // Flower 1
 images.add(new ImageIcon(...)); // Flower 2
 images.add(new ImageIcon(...)); // Flower 3
 images.add(new ImageIcon(...)); // Flower 4

 for (int index = 0; index < numberOfFlowersToCreate; index++) {
     int xPos = ...; // Calculate x position
     int yPos = ...; // Calculate y position

     Collections.shuffle(images);
     ImageIcon image = images.get(0);
     Flower flower = new Flower(image, xPos, yPos);

     // Do something with the instance of Flower
 }
```